Can't import libarchive-c in Python: FileNotFoundError
I am trying to selectively extract files from many 7zip files automatically, the usual patool and pyunpack and the like don't allow selection of files to be extracted. py7zr seems to provide the functionality however I find it extremely inefficient to extract individual files.
I found libarchive-c after crafting this Google query manually:
https://www.google.com/search?q=%22python%22+%227z%22+-patool+-pyunpack+-py7zr&tbs=li:1
And sifting through the trash it still returns.
I installed this version of libarchive, I downloaded the binary for Windows 10 x64 here.
I extracted the files from the libarchive package to D:\Programs\libarchive.
At first I can't even import libarchive:
In [20]: import libarchive
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [20], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import libarchive

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from .entry import ArchiveEntry
      2 from .exception import ArchiveError
      3 from .extract import extract_fd, extract_file, extract_memory

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\libarchive\entry.py:6, in <module>
      3 from enum import IntEnum
      4 import math
----> 6 from . import ffi
      9 class FileType(IntEnum):
     10     NAMED_PIPE     = AE_IFIFO  = 0o010000  # noqa: E221

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py:26, in <module>
     23 page_size = mmap.PAGESIZE
     25 libarchive_path = os.environ.get('LIBARCHIVE') or find_library('archive')
---> 26 libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
     29 # Constants
     31 ARCHIVE_EOF = 1       # Found end of archive.

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py:452, in LibraryLoader.LoadLibrary(self, name)
    451 def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 452     return self._dlltype(name)

File C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\ctypes\__init__.py:364, in CDLL.__init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    362 import nt
    363 mode = nt._LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS
--> 364 if '/' in name or '\\' in name:
    365     self._name = nt._getfullpathname(self._name)
    366     mode |= nt._LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

It is extremely easy to figure out what is wrong, at least for me. It is because of this line:
libarchive_path = os.environ.get('LIBARCHIVE') or find_library('archive')

It searches for the environment variable to file the path of libarchive library, but I downloaded a .zip package not an installer which doesn't set the environment variables, so the first command returns None. Of course it means the second command also failed.
So I had to manually supply the correct path. It is not well-documented, at least I haven't found it, but the line immediately below it is:
libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)

It means the path is expected to be a .dll path, so I changed it to this:
libarchive_path = "D:/Programs/libarchive/bin/archive.dll"

But I still can't import libarchive:
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'D:\Programs\libarchive\bin\archive.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

I have searched this error and have found a lot of irrelevant information. I have found many posts similar to this: Can't import dll module in Python
But they are all unhelpful, as I have supplied the absolute path while they are all dealing about relative path.
So the first part of the message is False, that must not be the case, the file must have been indeed found, or there is a serious bug in the library code, or the Python implementation...
Could it be there are other .dll files in that directory that this .dll depends on?
I have tried the following commands and they don't solve the issue:
os.chdir("D:/Programs/libarchive/bin")
os.add_dll_directory("D:/Programs/libarchive/bin")

And no, there is only one .dll in that directory:
PS D:\Programs\libarchive\bin> (gci).fullname
D:\Programs\libarchive\bin\archive.dll
D:\Programs\libarchive\bin\bsdcat.exe
D:\Programs\libarchive\bin\bsdcpio.exe
D:\Programs\libarchive\bin\bsdtar.exe
PS D:\Programs\libarchive\bin>

So how can I fix this?

Update
I used this program to find the .dll files imported by any executable:
import json
import os
import subprocess

def get_dependencies(exe):
    return [
        i["Name"] 
        for i in 
        json.loads(
            subprocess.run(
                ["D:/Programs/Dependencies_x64_Release/Dependencies.exe", "-json", "-imports", exe],
                capture_output=True,
                text=True
            ).stdout
        )["Imports"]
    ]


dependencies = get_dependencies("D:/Programs/libarchive/bin/archive.dll")

The .dll file imports the following files:
['bcrypt.dll',
 'libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll',
 'KERNEL32.dll',
 'VCRUNTIME140.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll']

I tried to find which are not present:
for dll in dependencies:
    if not os.path.isfile("C:/Windows/System32/" + dll):
        print(dll)

libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll

It seems I need to download libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, but what are the other files? It seems unlikely they are missing, but they aren't in the System32 folder.

"Could it be there are other .dll files in that directory that this .dll depends on?" -- the way to answer that is to inspect the dependency chain of the DLL. Other than a bunch of system libraries, it needs VCRUNTIME140.dll, and libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll (from OpenSSL I believe).

Regarding the api-ms-*.dll: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets IOW don't worry about them, they're aliases handled by the system, not necessarily physical DLLs.

Might be interesting to go over: [SO]: Load a DLL with dependencies in Python (@CristiFati's answer), [SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer), [SO]: How to install OpenSSL in windows 10? (@CristiFati's answer).

Thanks to this comment I was able to resolve the issue.
So I used this program to find dependencies of any executable file, I used the following code to filter out unnecessary information:
import json
import os
import subprocess

def get_dependencies(exe):
    return [
        i["Name"] 
        for i in 
        json.loads(
            subprocess.run(
                ["D:/Programs/Dependencies_x64_Release/Dependencies.exe", "-json", "-imports", exe],
                capture_output=True,
                text=True
            ).stdout
        )["Imports"]
    ]


dependencies = get_dependencies("D:/Programs/libarchive/bin/archive.dll")

I got this:
['bcrypt.dll',
 'libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll',
 'KERNEL32.dll',
 'VCRUNTIME140.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-locale-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll',
 'api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll']

I have quickly determined that libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll is missing, so I just downloaded it from here, I extracted the archive and copy-pasted the .dll to C:\Windows\System32 directory, and the issue is solved.

BTW, I would recommend against adding files into C:\Windows\System32. It's a bad habit from the early days of Windows, and just makes a mess of your system. Create some directory elsewhere, where you can store third party DLLs, and add that to user-specific (or even global) PATH. Otherwise, just drop it in the same directory that archive.dll is in.
